# How to limit scope of a constant to method/block

Tags: c#, scope, constants

Is there any way to limit the scope of a compile-time constant to a method/block of code that avoids hardcoding the value?

Something like the following:

```
public int SomeMethod(int a) {
    const int SomeCompileTimeConstant = 10; // obviously this doesn't exist

    return a + SomeCompileTimeConstant;
}
```

opposed to hardcoding the value:

```
public int SomeMethod(int a) {              
    return a + 10;
}
```

or making it a class-level constant:

```
public class A {
    private const int SomeCompileTimeConstant = 10;

    public int SomeMethod(int a) {
        return a + SomeCompileTimeConstant;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want that ? what is wrong with `return a + 10`?

Comment: What makes you think that "obviously it doesn't exist?"

Comment: `// obviously this doesn't exist` I am pretty sure it totally does

Comment: @Selman22 imagine using that value a bunch of times in your method/block. You wouldn't want to change every use of it if you need to change something.

Comment: the above comments are correct, have you tried this before asking? if you haven't you should

Comment: Your first example (the one you assume won't work) works just fine.

Comment: I had a syntax error originally in my code that made me think it wasn't possible. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a constant inside a function.

When you wrote

```
public int SomeMethod(int a) {
    const int SomeCompileTimeConstant = 10; // obviously this doesn't exist

    return a + SomeCompileTimeConstant;
}
```

you were wrong.

Comment: "You can declare a constant inside a function." - C# doesn't have functions. It has methods ;p But basically, +1